# Show that the predicate $x = 2$ is not definable in the set of positive integers with the predicates of equality and “$x$ divides $y$”

Tags: logic

I read about this in a logic book and was trying to solve it.
$$ $$
First I was trying to create an automorphism $$f : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N} $$
such that for any $x \in \Bbb{N}$, $f(x) = 2^x,$ and then it was easy to show that the predicate $x=2$ is not stable for $f$.
$$$$
But then I realized that an automorphism must be onto and one to one which $f$ isn't.
I was also trying to assume the predicate $x=2$ is definable and try to reach a contradiction but I didn't find a way. I was wondering if there is something that I am missing. Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: the divisibility relation can't distinguish prime numbers from each other. Try to find an automorphism that (for example) swaps $2$ and $3$. Consider the prime factorization of an arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: thats funny i did that just that and didn't check here, good to know then that its the correct way! tyvm!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbb{N}^+$ denote the set of positive integers and let $|$ denote the divisibility relation. Let’s start by thinking about what properties an arbitrary automorphism of the structure $(\mathbb{N}^+, |)$ must have.

Let $f: \mathbb{N}^+ \to \mathbb{N}^+$ be an automorphism. Since $f$ is an isomorphism, we have, for all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $$x \ | \ y \ \Longleftrightarrow \ f(x) \ | \ f(y).$$

Since $1$ is the only positive integer that divides every positive integer, we must have $$f(1) = 1.$$

For all $x,y \in \mathbb{N}^+$, $\text{lcm}(x,y)$ is the only positive integer that divides everything that both $x$ and $y$ divide. It follows that $$f(\text{lcm}(x,y)) = \text{lcm}(f(x),f(y)).$$

In particular, for all primes $p_1 \neq p_2$, we have $$f(p_1 p_2) = f(p_1) f(p_2).$$

(Think about why this follows from the above; it’s not entirely trivial.)

By a short inductive argument, (I'll let you work out the details!), we can prove that, for all $x \in \mathbb{N}^+$, we have $$f(x^n) = (f(x))^n.$$

In summary, we have these four observations about $f$:

- $f(1) = 1$
- $f(\text{lcm}(x,y)) = \text{lcm}(f(x),f(y))$
- $f(p_1 p_2) = f(p_1) f(p_2)$ for primes $p_1 \neq p_2$
- $f(x^n) = (f(x))^n$.

Combining these observations, we can prove that

- $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.

In other words, $f$ preserves products. So, once we specify how $f$ acts on $1$ and the primes, we have specified how $f$ acts everywhere, since every positive integer is a product of the primes.

Comment: "$\operatorname{lcm}(x,y)$ ... is divisible by everything that divides $x$, everything that divides $y$, and nothing more" - no, $\operatorname{lcm}(6,5)=30$ is divisible by $10$ which is not a divisor of $6$ or $5$.

Comment: Then wouldn't only the identity be the only automphrishm to keep the signature and it's predicates in this case? Hence is solving the question not related to automphrishm? Or am I wrong

Comment: Good point @aschepler, that was my mistake. I think I fixed it now.

Comment: @Giladbe10 Surprisingly, there are more automorphisms than just the identity, and defining a suitable automorphism is a good way to solve this problem. I added to my answer the additional observation that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: I found a soltion took me a while, if I simpliy take prime factrozintion of 2 and send it to another prime factoriztion it should work

Comment: @Giladbe10 Yes! And since 2 is a prime, you just need to send 2 to any other prime